# Fixing smelly paint

Tags: painting

I used a year old gallon of paint that smelled horrible when I opened it. While using it I thought the smell had gone away. However, I think I must have just been getting used to it. It has been 4 days and still smells bad. I wiped down the walls with vinegar water and it still smells. What do I to use to fix this? Bleach, repaint?

Comment: What kind of base is it? Latex, Oil, Acrylic?

Comment: It is latex paint

Comment: what does it smell like?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's going to be tough for us to remotely diagnose an odor. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Latex paints can indeed "spoil". What kind of smell is it? A chemical smell or a smell like sour milk or something moldy?